# Why do many websocket libraries implement their own application-level heartbeats?

Tags: node.js, http, websocket, socket.io

For example [socket.io](http://socket.io) has `pingInterval` and `pingTimeout` settings, [nes](https://github.com/hapijs/nes/blob/master/test/client.js#L1480) for hapi has similar heartbeat interval settings. This is ostensibly to prevent any intermediates such as over-zealous proxies from closing what seems to be an inactive connection.

But [ping/pong frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) are part of the websocket protocol and seem to serve the same purpose. So why do websocket library implementors add another layer of ping/pong at the application level?

If I was pushed to guess it would be in case the websocket server is dealing with a client that doesn't respond/support the websocket protocol level ping-pongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some reading up and made some tests and I think it comes down to this:

- Websocket `ping`s are initiated by the server only
- The browser Websocket API has isn't able to send `ping` frames and the incoming `ping`s from the server are not exposed in any way
- These pings are all about keepalive, not presence
- Therefore if the server goes away without a proper TCP teardown (network lost/crash etc), the client doesn't know if the connection is still open
- Adding a heartbeat at application level is a way for the client to establish the servers presence, or lack thereof. These must be sent as normal data messages because that's all the Websocket API (browser) is capable of.